# Pulling field depending on date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use a `select` statement to get specific fields from a database.  However, in my data the field-mapping changed on a specific date.

Is it possible for me to write something like a `CASE` expression to select one field if the date-column is before date `X` and another field on date `Y` and combine them in the same column?

Comment: It would help if you'd specify which exact sql-server you are using. Their dialects differ in subtle ways.

Comment: sorry, I am using Toad for Oracle 12

Comment: "Toad for Oracle 12" is just a client-side tool. The question was rather on the SQL DB engine/server used, which would be Oracle, probably version 12 (although the client version does not determine the server version).

Answer (score 3):

Sure use something like this:

```
select 
case when date-column < x 
then column1 
when date-column < y then column2 
end
```